# Products are not showing in child stores in magento

Tags: magento2, product, multistore, luma-theme

I am creating website in magento. I've created child stores in it.

```
 1. Main Website Store
 2. Shop 1
 3. Shop 2
```

Products are showing in main store in front-end but in child stores, products are not showing, it's giving me message **We can't find products matching the selection.**
**Here is the screenshot:**

[image]

Please help me

Comment: did you reindex ?

Comment: @PЯINCƏ how can i re-index?

Comment: You run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Yeah it worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reindex, you can do it like this :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```